# Did Double King grow another hand?

Tags: double-king

I was watching the short film Double King (by Felix Colgrave) for a film essay when I noticed either an animation mistake or a personal misunderstanding.

At about 6:28  they see their ring and cut off their fingers. They do this by pinning down their ringed hand with one hand and cutting off their fingers with another.

If you count the amount of hands shown in this scene, there are three (one too many for his species). I'm pretty sure the "hand" pinning down their ringed hand was actually his foot, but I'm not sure. How many hands does he have?

Comment: This look like a pretty bizarre animation. There's probably not much in the way of sense or continuity. Looks like they have another hand because they need another hand to hold the knife. Then when it's not necessary. they're back to two hands. I'm skeptical of the idea that there was intended to be an explanation other than "that's weird"

Comment: yeah, your right. i gotta stop overthinking things.

Comment: It's a good catch though. I didn't even notice it at first.